# Anyone know how to interact solidity smart contract using kotlin springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, solidity, smartcontracts, web3-java

Now I am working with kotlin springboot and what I have to make is that bridge feature.
Bridge contract has already been deployed. Please tell me how to connect with smart contract in Kotlin Springboot and how to call the function in Kotlin Springboot which is in solidity.
Thank you.

just trying to find some ways to solve the problem